# How to get a package name of .class file?

Tags: java, class, reflection, runtime, package

I have an unusual problem which is concerned to dynamic loading java .class file at run-time. All I want to do is to load a .class file and basing on it create a Class object.

Input: an absolute path of .class file.

Basing on it i want to load class by ClassLoader, so I need a path of root directory where file is located and full class name e.g com.test.MyClass. Basing on mentioned absolute path I can only get a class name but I can't get a package name which is "hiden" in this file.

Here is code of my "loading class method":

```
    public static void loadClass(String directory){

        // Get file root directory
        String rootDirectory = new File(directory).getParent();

        // Get rid of file extension
        String className = getFileNameWithoutExtension(directory);

        URL[] urls = null;
        ClassLoader cl = null;

        try {
            // Convert File to a URL and save them
            urls = new URL[]{new File(rootDirectory).toURI().toURL()};

            // Create a new class loader with the directory
            cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            // Load in the class
            dynamicClass = cl.loadClass(className);
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {

    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {

    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError e)
    {
        // Basing on error message get the class package name
        String classPackage = getClassPackage(e.getMessage());

        try {             

           // Load the class once more!
           dynamicClass = cl.loadClass(classPackage);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Second method is used to get package name from exception message:

```
private static String getClassPackage(String errorMsg){

    // Start and end index of cutting
    int startIndex = errorMsg.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
    int endIndex = errorMsg.length() - 1;

    // Let's save a substring
    String classPackage = errorMsg.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

    // Replace char '/' to '.'
    classPackage = classPackage.replace('/', '.');

    return classPackage;
}
```

Code of method **getFileNameWithoutExtension**:

```
private static String getFileNameWithoutExtension(String path){
    int start = path.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1;
    int end = path.lastIndexOf(DOT);
    end = start < end ? end : path.length();
    String name = path.substring(start, end);

    return name;
}
```

Where the static final variable is:

```
private static final String DOT = ".";
```

And here is my question: is it possible to get package name from .class file without using this kind of trick?

Comment: Why not just do `dynamicClass = cl.loadClass(className);` again? Besides, what exactly are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: I want to get a package name to insert it in constructor of ClassLoader: loadClass(>> here <<). When you invoke it you need a full name of class which includes a package name e.g: com.test.MyClass instead of MyClass. And all I want to get is this: com.test.MyClass before I load a class.

Comment: Please post your `getFileNameWithoutExtension` method.

Comment: I meant post it in the question... comments are horrible for structured code!

Comment: I think you mean "hidden". And again, please edit your question and add the code for `getFileNameWithoutExtension` **in** the question. In any case, the folder path is the same as the package name up until where the first package folder starts. Also, it's not clear what your actual results are. You have to put some form of debugging messages or something in your program to ensure it is running as you intend it to.

Comment: [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :) Will be waiting for the _Informed_ badge to appear on your profile... :D

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Foo.class.getPackage().getName()` method to determine this.

```
    public Package getPackage()
```

Returns:

> the package of the class, or null if no package information is available from the archive or codebase.

Using getName() :

```
    public String getName()
```

Returns:

> The fully-qualified name of this package as defined in section 6.5.3 of The Java™ Language Specification, for example, java.lang

Comment: OP wants to load a class from a .class file. Before it is loaded, they don't have a `Class<T>` instance. How would instance methods of `Class<T>` help OP in any way?

Comment: @RaphaelTarita well i guess six years later is enough time to realize i didn't answer the question lol

Comment: I originally came here because I helped a guy on the r/learnjava subreddit with a related issue and at first I thought getting the package name would be trivial. Turns out it's definitely not and I still haven't found an answer to this. Tbh I didn't realize that this question is six years old..

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the required data in `className`, just use it again. You don't need the `getClassPackage` method.

```
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError e)
    {
        // Basing on error message get the class package name
        //But we already have the class name in className variable!
        //String classPackage = getClassPackage(e.getMessage());

        try {             

           // Load the class once more!
           dynamicClass = cl.loadClass(className);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {

        }
    }
```

And if you want to get the package name only (not sure why), you can just get it from the class name:

```
String packageName = className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.'));
dynamicClass = cl.loadClass(packageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
String packName = new Object(){}.getClass().getPackage().getName();        
System.out.println(packName);
```